# How to conditionally override a value in an Eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I do:

```
Model::with('animal')->get()->each(function (&$item) {
    if (condition($item)) {
        $item->animal = 'Yop Override';
    }
})->toArray();
```

But I cannot override `animal`. Is there a way to do this?

My ugly alternative is:

```
array_map(function($item) {
    if (condition($item)) {
        $item['animal'] = 'Yop Override';
    }
    return $item;
}, Model::with('animal')->get()->toArray());
```

Comment: Is there a hardcoded string to assign?

Comment: @DrakulaPredator, I could be anything, this is not a strict example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is because you are trying to overwrite a relation of the model which you cannot do by a simple assignation.

You could achieve what you want with the `setRelation` method:

```
Model::with('animal')
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($item) {
        if (true) {
            $item->setRelation('animal', 'Yop override');
        }
    })
    ->toArray();
```

---

If you want to use the `map` method, it would be the same thing but you would have to add a return at the end of the function.

```
Model::with('animal')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($item) {
        if (true) {
            $item->setRelation('animal', 'Yop override');
        }

        return $item;
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: What is the difference with the `map` solution?

Comment: @nowox It will work with map as well. However, with `map`, you would have to return the `$item`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using `->each()`, you should be using `->map()` and returning `$item`.

Secondly, you need a `$key/$value` inside `function()`.

Thirdly, use the `use` when passing other data.

```
Model::with('animal')->get()->map(function ($model, $key) use (&$item) {
    if (condition($item)) {
        $item->animal = 'Yop Override';
    }
    return $item;
})->toArray();
```

Comment: He is trying to modify the attribute of the model, not another `$item` variable.

Comment: @ChinLeung Thank you for mentioning